# How to randomly shuffle "tiles" in a numpy array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, shuffle

I have an nxn numpy array, and I would like to divide it evenly into nxn tiles and randomly shuffle these, while retaining the pattern inside the tiles.

For example, if I have an array that's size (200,200), I want to be able to divide this into say 16 arrays of size (50,50), or even 64 arrays of size (25,25), and randomly shuffle these, while retaining the same shape of the original array (200,200) and retaining the order of numbers inside of the smaller arrays.

I have looked up specific numpy functions, and I found the numpy.random.shuffle(x) function, but this will randomly shuffle the individual elements of an array. I would only like to shuffle these smaller arrays within the larger array.

Is there any numpy function or quick way that will do this? I'm not sure where to begin.

**EDIT**: To further clarify exactly what I want:

Let's say I have an input 2D array of shape (10,10) of values:

```
0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19
20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29
30  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39
40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49
50  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59
60  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69
70  71  72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79
80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89
90  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99
```

I choose a tile size such that it fits evenly into this array, so since this array has shape (10,10), I can either choose to split this into 4 (5,5) tiles, or 25 (2,2) tiles. So if I choose 4 (5,5) tiles, I want to randomly shuffle these tiles that results in an output array that could look like this:

```
50  51  52  53  54  0   1   2   3   4
60  61  62  63  64  10  11  12  13  14
70  71  72  73  74  20  21  22  23  24
80  81  82  83  84  30  31  32  33  34
90  91  92  93  94  40  41  42  43  44
55  56  57  58  59  5   6   7   8   9
65  66  67  68  69  15  16  17  18  19
75  76  77  78  79  25  26  27  28  29
85  86  87  88  89  35  36  37  38  39
95  96  97  98  99  45  46  47  48  49
```

Every array (both the input array, the output array, and the separate tiles) would be squares, so that when randomly shuffled the size and dimension of the main array stays the same (10,10).

Comment: Do you mean that each row stays exactly the same, and the order of the rows is different? Or do you mean that one number can jump rows, but that it should stay in the same column? Or do you mean that numbers can jump columns and rows as long as the resulting rows match some pattern, such as ascending order in the row? These are three very different outputs and your description, it seems, could be any of them.

Comment: Yes, to clarify I mean that the number itself can jump rows and columns, but I want the actual smaller 4x4 matrix to stay in tact through this random shuffling of tiles. I'll try to edit my post to make a sample output of what I want

Comment: Always a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is my solution using loop

```py
import numpy as np

arr = np.arange(36).reshape(6,6)

def suffle_section(arr, n_sections):

    assert arr.shape[0]==arr.shape[1], "arr must be square"
    assert arr.shape[0]%n_sections == 0, "arr size must divideable into equal n_sections"

    size = arr.shape[0]//n_sections


    new_arr = np.empty_like(arr)
    ## randomize section's row index

    rand_indxes = np.random.permutation(n_sections*n_sections)

    for i in range(n_sections):
        ## randomize section's column index
        for j in  range(n_sections):

            rand_i = rand_indxes[i*n_sections + j]//n_sections
            rand_j = rand_indxes[i*n_sections + j]%n_sections

            new_arr[i*size:(i+1)*size, j*size:(j+1)*size] = \
                arr[rand_i*size:(rand_i+1)*size, rand_j*size:(rand_j+1)*size]

    return new_arr


result = suffle_section(arr, 3)


display(arr)
display(result)

array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17],
       [18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23],
       [24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
       [30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35]])

array([[ 4,  5, 16, 17, 24, 25],
       [10, 11, 22, 23, 30, 31],
       [14, 15,  2,  3,  0,  1],
       [20, 21,  8,  9,  6,  7],
       [26, 27, 12, 13, 28, 29],
       [32, 33, 18, 19, 34, 35]])
```

Comment: Just got back to this - thanks for the solution. This is extremely close, but it seems that the top three blocks (with the top left corner being 0, 2, and 4) are always shuffled together, so that even if the row is random, they end up being in the same row. But I can simply take a matrix, shuffle it using your function, transpose it, and shuffle again, and I think that should work, something like this: result = suffle_section(suffle_section(arr, 5).T,5).T

Comment: @gram_schmidt you caught it well, I have corrected it now. before it was shuffling rows and columns separately which wasn't taking all the permutations possible shuffle. Now I have shuffled all total count of section at once and calculated row and column based on it

Answer (score 1):

We will use `np.random.shuffle` alongwith axes permutations to achieve the desired results. There are two interpretations to it. Hence, two solutions.

**Shuffle randomly within each block**

Elements in each block are randomized and that same randomized order is maintaiined in all blocks.

```
def randomize_tiles_shuffle_within(a, M, N):
    # M,N are the height and width of the blocks
    m,n = a.shape
    b = a.reshape(m//M,M,n//N,N).swapaxes(1,2).reshape(-1,M*N)
    np.random.shuffle(b.T)
    return b.reshape(m//M,n//N,M,N).swapaxes(1,2).reshape(a.shape)
```

**Shuffle randomly blocks w.r.t each other**

Blocks are randomized w.r.t each other, while keeping the order within each block same as in the original array.

```
def randomize_tiles_shuffle_blocks(a, M, N):    
    m,n = a.shape
    b = a.reshape(m//M,M,n//N,N).swapaxes(1,2).reshape(-1,M*N)
    np.random.shuffle(b)
    return b.reshape(m//M,n//N,M,N).swapaxes(1,2).reshape(a.shape)
```

Sample runs -

```
In [47]: a
Out[47]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17],
       [18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23],
       [24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
       [30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35]])

In [48]: randomize_tiles_shuffle_within(a, 3, 3)
Out[48]: 
array([[ 1,  7, 13,  4, 10, 16],
       [14,  8, 12, 17, 11, 15],
       [ 0,  6,  2,  3,  9,  5],
       [19, 25, 31, 22, 28, 34],
       [32, 26, 30, 35, 29, 33],
       [18, 24, 20, 21, 27, 23]])

In [49]: randomize_tiles_shuffle_blocks(a, 3, 3)
Out[49]: 
array([[ 3,  4,  5, 18, 19, 20],
       [ 9, 10, 11, 24, 25, 26],
       [15, 16, 17, 30, 31, 32],
       [ 0,  1,  2, 21, 22, 23],
       [ 6,  7,  8, 27, 28, 29],
       [12, 13, 14, 33, 34, 35]])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to `skimage` (it comes with Spyder) you could use [`view_as_blocks`](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.util.html#skimage.util.view_as_blocks):

```
from skimage.util import view_as_blocks

def shuffle_tiles(arr, m, n):
    a_= view_as_blocks(arr,(m,n)).reshape(-1,m,n)
    # shuffle works along 1st dimension and in-place
    np.random.shuffle(a_)
    return a_
```

Comment: Thanks, this is definitely close but when I use this with an array of shape (10,10) and four tiles of size (5,5), this function returns an array with shape (4,5,5)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach that tries hard to avoid unnecessary copies:

```
import numpy as np

def f_pp(a,bs):
    i,j = a.shape
    k,l = bs
    esh = i//k,k,j//l,l
    bc = esh[::2]
    sh1,sh2 = np.unravel_index(np.random.permutation(bc[0]*bc[1]),bc)
    ns1,ns2 = np.unravel_index(np.arange(bc[0]*bc[1]),bc)
    out = np.empty_like(a)
    out.reshape(esh)[ns1,:,ns2] = a.reshape(esh)[sh1,:,sh2]
    return out
```

Timings:

```
pp 0.41529153706505895
dv 1.3133141631260514
br 1.6034217830747366
```

Test script (continued)

```
# Divakar
def f_dv(a,bs):
    M,N = bs
    m,n = a.shape
    b = a.reshape(m//M,M,n//N,N).swapaxes(1,2).reshape(-1,M*N)
    np.random.shuffle(b)
    return b.reshape(m//M,n//N,M,N).swapaxes(1,2).reshape(a.shape)

from skimage.util import view_as_blocks

# Brenlla shape fixed by pp
def f_br(arr,bs):
    m,n = bs
    a_= view_as_blocks(arr,(m,n))
    sh = a_.shape
    a_ = a_.reshape(-1,m,n)
    # shuffle works along 1st dimension and in-place
    np.random.shuffle(a_)
    return a_.reshape(sh).swapaxes(1,2).reshape(arr.shape)

ex = np.arange(100000).reshape(1000,100)
bs = 10,10
tst = np.tile(np.arange(np.prod(bs)).reshape(bs),np.floor_divide(ex.shape,bs))

from timeit import timeit
for n,f in list(globals().items()):
    if n.startswith('f_'):
        assert (tst==f(tst,bs)).all()
        print(n[2:],timeit(lambda:f(ex,bs),number=1000))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's code to shuffle row order but keep row items exactly as is:

```
import numpy as np 
np.random.seed(0)

#creates a 6x6 array
a = np.random.randint(0,100,(6,6))
a
array([[44, 47, 64, 67, 67,  9],
       [83, 21, 36, 87, 70, 88],
       [88, 12, 58, 65, 39, 87],
       [46, 88, 81, 37, 25, 77],
       [72,  9, 20, 80, 69, 79],
       [47, 64, 82, 99, 88, 49]])

#creates a number for each row index, 0,1,2,3,4,5
order = np.arange(6)

#shuffle index array
np.random.shuffle(order)

#make new array in shuffled order
shuffled = np.array([a[y] for y in order])
shuffled
array([[46, 88, 81, 37, 25, 77],
       [88, 12, 58, 65, 39, 87],
       [83, 21, 36, 87, 70, 88],
       [47, 64, 82, 99, 88, 49],
       [44, 47, 64, 67, 67,  9],
       [72,  9, 20, 80, 69, 79]])
```